# weird problem with latest versions of Chrome loading an xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I don't run a web server to test web sites. Instead I just load them as files in a web browser on my development machine.

I have a web page that loads a list of clubs from an XML file and displays them using javascript. For some reason it stopped working with the latest version of Chrome but only on Windows 10 and Macs. To make matters even stranger, when I set up a test directory on a live server to make sure it wasn't caused by trying to access a local file, it worked.

The files in the test directory are the html, xml and css files plus the 3 javascript files needed to load and display the file. The file ownerships and permissions are identical between the root (live) directory and the test directory (33 www-data; and rw rw r).

To make it even stranger, I noticed a display bug when when accessing the file from Chromium running on my Linux box that also disappears in the test directory. Chromium also can't display the file when I run it locally.

Here's where it gets really weird. The current code seems to be working OK with Windows 10 when I load it locally or from the test directory but not from the root directory on the web site. With Chrome v77:

W:/Lions%20Clubs/A711/site/clubs.html works.
* http://www.a711lions.ca/clubs.html doesn't work.
* http://www.a711lions.ca/test/clubs.html works.

with Chromium v76:

W:/Lions%20Clubs/A711/site/clubs.html doesn't work.
* http://www.a711lions.ca/clubs.html works but display isn't quite right.
* http://www.a711lions.ca/test/clubs.html works.

I did run both my code and the xml file through checkers and both are good. The javascript show the limitations of the lint checker while the xml tests clean.

Initially I thought the problem was that Chrome didn't like synchronous calls with XMLHttpRequest so I converted it to use asynchronous. The code below reads the table. This is what I am currently using. The loadTable function in the event listener is what starts the display process.

Putting various alerts in the code, I discovered that when it fails, the loadListener function is never invoked. I get the opened file and sent request alerts but not the listener activated one.

```
function loadListener() {
alert('listener activated');    
    var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
    if (xmlDoc) {
        loadTable(xmlDoc);
    } else {
        alert('xmlDoc is empty');
    }
}

function importXML(fileName) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
      var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", loadListener);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", fileName);
alert('opened file')
    xmlhttp.send();
alert('sent request');    
}
```

When the code works, it displays a nicely formatted list of clubs. When it doesn't, it displays clubs.html but no clubs. With Chromium v76 on the live file, it shows each club card half width but displays fine in the test directory.

With every other browser I've tried, it displays properly.

Comment: `Chrom(e|ium)` updates always break something - wait for the next update and it'll work again - this has been my experience with Chrome for the last 7 years, and why the company I work for has stopped recommending Chrome to our clients

Comment: You're right. It doesn't even show up on all the Windows 10 machines I try. I have a W10 VM that it shows up on but it didn't show up on a real W10 machine I have access to. I'm only getting scattered reports of the problem...

Comment: I tried adding error and progress listeners but they weren't being triggered. :(

Comment: Found a workaround. By changing the html file to load the javascript from the test directory, and changing that javascript to load the xml file from the test directory, I can keep the html file on the web site's root.

It's not perfect since it screws up my templating - I have to modify the standard headers to point to the test folders and Chromium v76 still doesn't load the files locally and messes them up when loaded from the web site.

Comment: Found a better workaround. I just have to keep the xml files off the site root. Unfortunately now my site won't run from a file share - I have to run it from a real web server.